# Is There an O(1) Way To Give Haskell Read Access to C-style Arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, haskell

I want to call a Haskell function from C++:

```
a = f(x);
```

where f is a Haskell function.

x is `double[]` in cpp.

Whatever stateful mutations happen to x will happen in C++. For example,

```
x[42] = x[41] + pi;
```

and it would be really nice if I could make Haskell see `[Double]`.

I can think of some O(N) ways of constructing a new `[Double]` every time I call `f`, but I'm looking for an O(1) way.

Please note that only read access is needed.

Is there an O(1) way to do this?

Comment: What Haskell implementation are you using?

Comment: Why would you want Haskell to see `[Double]`? This is clearly a case for arrays/vectors. Even reading from an already existing list isn't O(1). If you actually mean O(k) where _k_ is the highest index that you read in, then this can be accomplished by lazily converting (streaming) the array to a list.

Comment: A C-style array fundamentally does not look like a Haskell `[Double]` in memory. The C array is just a contiguous chunk of memory with doubles directly in it. A Haskell `[Double]` is a linked list of pointers to doubles, so Haskell functions on that type are going to read the nth entry by chasing pointers. A C-style array is going to have to be converted to this *extremely* different format before being read by such Haskell functions, which is never going to be O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact thing you ask for, `[Double]`, is not possible in O(1) unless you're willing to start doing amortized-O(1) style things. But as an alternative, you might like [`Data.Vector.Storable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html#g:39) if there comes a point where mutation finishes, or [`Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#g:15) if not.

Comment: I mean... it probably is possible *somehow*.  Each number in the list will have an address in memory, so you can go futz with it if you can find it.  Whether that's exposed in the API is another matter...

Comment: @luqui If I understand correctly, you are proposing creating a list of the right length, then using unsafe hackery to modify the values in that list to match the array coming from C++. If so, then I believe the first step -- create a list of the right length -- is already not O(1).

Comment: The question mentions that `f` will be called multiple times.  So I meant create the list once, then, maybe with an array mapping indices to their corresponding memory addresses, modify it like an array before each function call.  Anyway, it seems a bit convoluted, but it's better than "not possible".  Maybe more like "not advised."